# Why ++str operation causes error if array is char *str[] but not in case of char *argv[] (one of the argument to the main function)?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have written small piece of code to understand how to traverse through array of char pointers & 2D array of characters. I've used
**1]** and **2]** while printing the o/p **to just keep track of which block of code prints what**, kindly ignore them.

The similar code for printing o/p is used for traversing through 3 different (types of) arrays:-

a) Array of Character Pointers: char *argv[]

b) Array of Character Pointers: char *str[]

c) 2D Array of Characters: char strarr[][7]

The basic operation I performed are as follows: If char *foo[] then

A) foo points 1st element (string) of foo (doubtful about this one)

B) *++foo points to 1st char of next element of foo

C) **++foo gives 1st char of next element of foo

D) ++*foo points to next char within element of foo

E) *++*foo gives next char within element of foo

The operations A, B, C & D are allowed only in case of char *argv[].
char *str[] allows only operations C & D; while 2D array char strarr[][7] doesn't allow all A-D.

I understand why operation C & D are allowed for char *str[] and not for char strarr[][7]:
Since char *str[] is an array pointers and the increment of value its elements (i.e. value of address to string) is allowed while in case of char strarr[]2[7] is 2D array of element it is not possible to increment the address of its elements.

**Correct me for any wrong assumptions.**

But I am not able to understand why operation of **++str, *++str or
++str is not allowed whereas **++argv *++argv or ++argv is allowed?

Both argv and str are array of char pointers then why this different behavior? (str points to str[0] then why ++str causes error instead of pointing to str[1]?) Is char *argv[] is some special kind of array or operations on it performed in some other way/method?

When I write **++str, *++str or ++str the compiler gives the following error:

> gcc -Wall -c "TestProg.c" (in directory:
>   /home/crownedeagle/Downloads/CDAC C-CAT/C - K&R Solutions) TestProg.c:
>   In function ‘main’: TestProg.c:61:33: error: lvalue required as
>   increment operand   printf("\n1]\n**++str = %c", **++str);
>                          ^

### Here is the code:

```
//Pointer of Array and Array Pointer Experimentation

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    if (argc == 7)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
            printf("%s\t\t%p\n", argv[i], argv[i]);

        printf("\n0]\n**argv = %c", **argv);
        printf("\n*argv = %s", *argv);

        printf("\n1]\nargv = %p", argv);
        printf("\n*argv = %s", *argv);
        printf("\n**++argv = %c", **++argv);
        printf("\nargv = %p", argv);
        printf("\n*argv = %s", *argv);
        printf("\n**++argv = %c", **++argv);
        printf("\nargv = %p", argv);
        printf("\n*argv = %s", *argv);      

        printf("\n2]\nargv = %p", argv);
        printf("\n&(argv[0]) = %p", &(argv[0]));
        printf("\n*argv = %p", *argv);
        printf("\n&(**argv) = %p", &(**argv));

        printf("\n*++*argv = %c", *++*argv);
        printf("\n*argv = %s", *argv);

        printf("\nargv = %p", argv);
        printf("\n&(argv[0]) = %p", &(argv[0]));
        printf("\n*argv = %p", *argv);
        printf("\n&(**argv) = %p", &(**argv));

        printf("\nargv[0] = %s", argv[0]);

        printf("\n\n");

        for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
            printf("%s\t\t%p\n", argv[i], argv[i]);
    }

    char *str[] = {"ABCDEF", "HIJKLM", "OPQRST", "VWXYZA", "123456"};

    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            printf("%s\t\t%p\n", str[i], str[i]);

    printf("\n0]\n**str = %c", **str);
    printf("\n*str = %s", *str);

    //printf("\n1]\n**++str = %c", **++str);
    //printf("\n*str = %s", *str);

    printf("\n1]\nstr = %p", str);
    printf("\n&(str[0]) = %p", &(str[0]));
    printf("\n*str = %p", *str);
    printf("\n&(**str) = %p", &(**str));

    printf("\n*++*str = %c", *++*str);
    printf("\n*str = %s", *str);

    printf("\nstr = %p", str);
    printf("\n&(str[0]) = %p", &(str[0]));
    printf("\n*str = %p", *str);
    printf("\n&(**str) = %p", &(**str));

    printf("\nstr[0] = %s", str[0]);

    printf("\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            printf("%s\t\t%p\n", str[i], str[i]);

    char strarr[][7] = {"ABCDEF", "HIJKLM", "OPQRST", "VWXYZA", "123456"};

    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            printf("%s\t\t%p\n", strarr[i], strarr[i]);

    printf("\n0]\n**strarr = %c", **strarr);
    printf("\n*strarr = %s", *strarr);

    //printf("\n1]\n**++strarr = %c", **++strarr);
    //printf("\n*strarr = %s", *strarr);

    printf("\n1]\nstrarr = %p", strarr);
    printf("\n&(strarr[0]) = %p", &(strarr[0]));
    printf("\n*strarr = %p", *strarr);
    printf("\n&(**strarr) = %p", &(**strarr));

    //printf("\n*++*strarr = %c", *++*strarr);
    printf("\n*strarr = %s", *strarr);

    printf("\nstrarr = %p", strarr);
    printf("\n&(strarr[0]) = %p", &(strarr[0]));
    printf("\n*strarr = %p", *strarr);
    printf("\n&(**strarr) = %p", &(**strarr));

    printf("\nstrarr[0] = %s", strarr[0]);

    printf("\n\n"); 

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            printf("%s\t\t%p\n", strarr[i], strarr[i]);

    return 0;   
}
```

### The output of code is:

> ```
> crownedeagle@EagleNest:~/C - K&R Solutions$ ./TestProg abcdef hijklm opqrst vwxyza 123456 789012
>
>     ./TestProg    0x7ffd61c027c7
>     abcdef        0x7ffd61c027d2
>     hijklm        0x7ffd61c027d9
>     opqrst        0x7ffd61c027e0
>     vwxyza        0x7ffd61c027e7
>     123456        0x7ffd61c027ee
>     789012        0x7ffd61c027f5
>
>     0]
>     **argv = .
>     *argv = ./TestProg
>     1]
>     argv = 0x7ffd61c01c98
>     *argv = ./TestProg
>     **++argv = a
>     argv = 0x7ffd61c01ca0
>     *argv = abcdef
>     **++argv = h
>     argv = 0x7ffd61c01ca8
>     *argv = hijklm
>     2]
>     argv = 0x7ffd61c01ca8
>     &(argv[0]) = 0x7ffd61c01ca8
>     *argv = 0x7ffd61c027d9
>     &(**argv) = 0x7ffd61c027d9
>     *++*argv = i
>     *argv = ijklm
>     argv = 0x7ffd61c01ca8
>     &(argv[0]) = 0x7ffd61c01ca8
>     *argv = 0x7ffd61c027da
>     &(**argv) = 0x7ffd61c027da
>     argv[0] = ijklm
>
>     ijklm         0x7ffd61c027da
>     opqrst        0x7ffd61c027e0
>     vwxyza        0x7ffd61c027e7
>     123456        0x7ffd61c027ee
>     789012        0x7ffd61c027f5
>     (null)        (nil)
>     XDG_VTNR=7    0x7ffd61c027fc
>
>     ABCDEF        0x400dfa
>     HIJKLM        0x400e01
>     OPQRST        0x400e08
>     VWXYZA        0x400e0f
>     123456        0x400e16
>
>     0]
>     **str = A
>     *str = ABCDEF
>     1]
>     str = 0x7ffd61c01b80
>     &(str[0]) = 0x7ffd61c01b80
>     *str = 0x400dfa
>     &(**str) = 0x400dfa
>     *++*str = B
>     *str = BCDEF
>     str = 0x7ffd61c01b80
>     &(str[0]) = 0x7ffd61c01b80
>     *str = 0x400dfb
>     &(**str) = 0x400dfb
>     str[0] = BCDEF
>
>     BCDEF         0x400dfb
>     HIJKLM        0x400e01
>     OPQRST        0x400e08
>     VWXYZA        0x400e0f
>     123456        0x400e16
>
>     ABCDEF        0x7ffd61c01b50
>     HIJKLM        0x7ffd61c01b57
>     OPQRST        0x7ffd61c01b5e
>     VWXYZA        0x7ffd61c01b65
>     123456        0x7ffd61c01b6c
>
>     0]
>     **strarr = A
>     *strarr = ABCDEF
>     1]
>     strarr = 0x7ffd61c01b50
>     &(strarr[0]) = 0x7ffd61c01b50
>     *strarr = 0x7ffd61c01b50
>     &(**strarr) = 0x7ffd61c01b50
>     *strarr = ABCDEF
>     strarr = 0x7ffd61c01b50
>     &(strarr[0]) = 0x7ffd61c01b50
>     *strarr = 0x7ffd61c01b50
>     &(**strarr) = 0x7ffd61c01b50
>     strarr[0] = ABCDEF
>
>     ABCDEF        0x7ffd61c01b50
>     HIJKLM        0x7ffd61c01b57
>     OPQRST        0x7ffd61c01b5e
>     VWXYZA        0x7ffd61c01b65
>     123456        0x7ffd61c01b6c
> ```

Comment: If I understand the question, I believe it has to do with the fact that arrays passed as arguments to functions "decay" to pointers. [Why do arrays in C decay to pointers?](//stackoverflow.com/q/33291624)

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `printf("\n&(str[0]) = %p", &(str[0]));`  This is trying to take the address of an address.  The compiler outputs: `71:28: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char **’ [-Wformat=]

Comment: regarding this kind of statement: `printf("\n&(strarr[0]) = %p", &(strarr[0]));`  This is trying to take the address of an address  The compiler outputs: `:94:29: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[7]’ [-Wformat=]`

Comment: The compiler, for the OPs posted code, outputs 15 warnings (as exemplified in the above 2 comments).   When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Answer (score 3):

In this function declaration

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

the compiler adjusts the parameter having the array of unknown size type to pointer to the element type. That is this declaration is equivalent to

```
int main(int argc, char **argv )
```

So within the function you are dealing with a pointer and you may apply increment or assignment operators.

For example these function declarations

```
void f( int a[100] );
void f( int a[10] );
void f( int a[] );
```

declare the same one function and all the declarations are adjusted by the compiler to the declaration

```
void f( int *a );
```

From the C Standard (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes))

> 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted
>   to ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any)
>   are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation.
>   If the keyword static also appears within the [ and ] of the array
>   type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the
>   corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first
>   element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the
>   size expression.

In this declaration

```
char *str[] = {"ABCDEF", "HIJKLM", "OPQRST", "VWXYZA", "123456"};
```

there is declared an array of the type `char * [5]`. Arrays are non-modifiable lvalues. So you may not apply to arrays increment or assignment operators.

Comment: In the last line of your answer what should be the value within [ and ] in char * [5] part? It is the string length and should be 6? or 7?

Comment: @CrownedEagle It is the number of initializers in the braces of the type char *. So the array has the type char *[5]

Comment: Okk got it.. Thanks..
Let me go through your answer one more time to try understand it.

Answer (score 0):

the order of execution of urinary operators is from right to left so:

```
* & + - ! ~ ++expr --expr
```

means the ++ is executed first then **.

regarding:

```
     printf("\n1]\n**++str = %c", **++str);
```

so,  `++str` results in the `str[1]` pointer

de-reference it once via '*' results in the string pointed to by `str[1]`

The second de-reference via '*' results in garbage as the string where: `str[1]` points is not a pointer

Comment: Isn't 2nd derefference should give the 1st character of str[1] since I am using %c format specifier?